# Facebook Graph API, how to get users email?

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Graph API, but I can't figure out how to get a logged-in users email address.

The intro to Graph states "The Graph API can provide access to all of the basic account registration data you would typically request in a sign-up form for your site, including name, email address, profile picture, and birthday"

All well and good, but how do I access that info?

This is what I have so far:

```
$json = $facebook->api('/me');

$first = $json['first_name']; // gets first name
$last = $json['last_name'];
```

Comment: what does `var_dump($obj);` output?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The only way to get the users e-mail address is to request extended permissions on the email field.  The user must allow you to see this and you cannot get the e-mail addresses of the user's friends.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

You can do this if you are using Facebook connect by passing scope=email in the get string of your call to the Auth Dialog.

I'd recommend using an [SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) instead of file_get_contents as it makes it far easier to perform the [Oauth](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) authentication.

Comment: Okay, changed file_get_contents. But I'm a little confused as to where I would pass the req_perms=email.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out:

$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'email'))

Comment: It wasn't completely obvious to me based on this answer... if you're using the JavaScript API, you want to use `FB.api('/me?scope=email', function(apiResponse) { ... });`

Answer (score 64):

```
// Facebook SDK v5 for PHP
// https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/5.0.0

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
]);

$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
$response = $fb->get('/me?locale=en_US&fields=name,email');
$userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
var_dump(
    $userNode->getField('email'), $userNode['email']
);
```

Comment: Is there somewhere a reference page describing the `/me` route? I keep browsing the pages on [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference) and can't find it anywhere :(

Comment: /me?locale=en_US&fields=name,email was the only way I could figure out to get it to return the email address, couldn't find any other reference to this online

Comment: here are docs - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/ @RaduMurzea

Comment: This is the correct answer, although a simpler explanation may be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349618/in-facebook-graph-api-what-are-the-api-calls-to-get-a-users-email-address

Comment: thank you for this.. nothing else worked except this. now it's working fine! :)

Answer (score 19):

Open base_facebook.php 
Add Access_token at function `getLoginUrl()`

```
array_merge(array(
                  'access_token' => $this->getAccessToken(),
                  'client_id' => $this->getAppId(),
                  'redirect_uri' => $currentUrl, // possibly overwritten
                  'state' => $this->state),
             $params);
```

and Use scope for Email Permission

```
if ($user) {
   echo $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
   echo $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email,read_stream'));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just add these code block on status return, and start passing a query string object {}. For JavaScript devs

After initializing your sdk.

step 1: // get login status

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
        console.log(response);
    });
  });
```

This will check on document load and get your login status check if users has been logged in.

Then the function **checkLoginState** is called, and response is pass to **statusChangeCallback**

```
function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }
```

Step 2: Let you get the response data from the status

```
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    // body...
    if(response.status === 'connected'){
      // setElements(true);
      let userId = response.authResponse.userID;
      // console.log(userId);
      console.log('login');
      getUserInfo(userId);

    }else{
      // setElements(false);
      console.log('not logged in !');
    }
  }
```

This also has the **userid** which is being set to variable, then a **getUserInfo** func is called to fetch user information using the Graph-api.

```
function getUserInfo(userId) {
    // body...
    FB.api(
      '/'+userId+'/?fields=id,name,email',
      'GET',
      {},
      function(response) {
        // Insert your code here
        // console.log(response);
        let email = response.email;
        loginViaEmail(email);
      }
    );
  }
```

After passing the **userid** as an argument, the function then fetch all information relating to that **userid**. Note: in my case i was looking for the email, as to allowed me run a function that can logged user via email only.

// login via email

```
function loginViaEmail(email) {
    // body...
    let token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';

    let data = {
      _token:token,
      email:email
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: '/login/via/email',    
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: data,
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if(data.status == 'success'){
          window.location.href = '/dashboard';
        }

        if(data.status == 'info'){
          window.location.href = '/create-account'; 
        }
      },
      error: function(data){
        console.log('Error logging in via email !');
        // alert('Fail to send login request !');
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hello @Pang, you can check now, i think this might help. but better still you can still comment more issues.

Comment: +hero status, just for '/'+userId+'/?fields=id,name,email' which isn't specified in the documentation

Answer (score 6):

To get the user email, you have to log in the user with his Facebook account using the `email` permission. Use for that the Facebook PHP SDK ([see on github](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)) as following.

First check if the user is already logged in :

```
require "facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
    'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $user = null;
    }
}
```

If he his not, you can display the login link asking for the `email` permission :

```
if (!$user) {
    $args = array('scope' => 'email');
    echo '<a href="' . $facebook->getLoginUrl() . '">Login with Facebook</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">Logout</a>';
}
```

When he is logged in the email can be found in the `$user_profile` array.

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you've requested email permissions when the user logged in from your app and you have a valid token,

With the **fetch api** you can just

```
const token = "some_valid_token";
const response = await fetch(
        `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email&access_token=${token}`
      );
const result = await response.json();
```

result will be:

```
{
    "id": "some_id",
    "email": "name@example.org"
}
```

id will be returned anyway.

You can add to the fields query param more stuff, but you need permissions for them if they are not on the public profile (name is public).

```
?fields=name,email,user_birthday&token=
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Comment: Love an answer that does not assume the use of an SDK that is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve the email address from the logged in user's profile. Here is the code snippet

```
<?php

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $initMe["appId"],
      'secret' => $initMe["appSecret"],
    ));

    $facebook->setAccessToken($initMe["accessToken"]);
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        print_r($user_profile["email"]);
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is not working for me. `$user_profile` does not contains email

Answer (score 3):

First, activate your application at the [Facebook Developer center](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/). Applications in development mode are not allowed to retrieve the e-mail field.

If the user is not logged in, you need to login and specify that your application/site will need the e-mail field.

```
FB.login(
    function(response) {
         console.log('Welcome!');
    },
    {scope: 'email'}
);
```

Then, after the login, or if the user is already logged, retrieve the e-mail using the Facebook API, specifying the field email:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email'}, (response) => {
    console.log(response.name + ', ' + response.email);
    console.log('full response: ', response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

https://graph.facebook.com/me

will give you info about the currently logged-in user, but you'll need to supply an oauth token. See:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user

Comment: you can't get it without extended permission.

Comment: or without specifying the fields parameter '/me/?fields=id,name,email' which isn't specified in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

The email in the profile can be obtained using extended permission but I Guess it's not possible to get the email used to login fb. In my app i wanted to display mulitple fb accounts of a user in a list, i wanted to show the login emails of fb accounts as a unique identifier of the respective accounts but i couldn't get it off from fb, all i got was the primary email in the user profile but in my case my login email and my primary email are different.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Facebook application is published. In order to receive data for email, public_profile and user_friends your app must be made available to public.

You can disable it later for development purposes and still get email field.

Answer (score 0):

The following tools can be useful during development:

> Access Token Debugger: Paste in an access token for details

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

> Graph API Explorer: Test requests to the graph api after pasting in your access token

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to fully specify the version number of the API as something like `"v2.11"` and not `"2.11"`

I'm not sure what it defaults to if this is incorrect, but I got some odd errors trying to just retrieve the email when I missed the `v`.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem with collecting user's email addres on PHP side (getGraphUser() method) was, that the default behavior of facebook-rendered button (on WEBSIDE side, created with xfbml=1) is to implicity calling FB.login() with the scope NOT including "email".

That means you MUST:

1) call

```
FB.login(....,{scope: email})
```

manifestly, creating your own button to start login process

OR

2) add scope="email" attribute to the xfbml button

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-
layout="rounded" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true" data-
width="1000px" scope="email"></div>
```

to be able to collect email address on PHP side.

Hope it helps.