# Facebook - how to get email from ID?

Tags: php, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Facebook Graph API, how to get users email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611682/facebook-graph-api-how-to-get-users-email)

I am playing with Facebook API and trying to get available information from it.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => 'id', 'secret' => 'key'));  
print_r($facebook->api('/my_username_or_id'));
```

which prints out:

```
Array ( [id] => my_id [name] => whole_name [first_name] => first_name [last_name] => last_name [link] => url_to_profile [username] => username [gender] => gener [locale] => es_LA )
```

But not email.
When I go to [Facebook developer test site](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me) and set up my username or ID, I get something like this:

```
{
  "id": "id", 
  "name": "name", 
  "first_name": "first_name", 
  "last_name": "last_name", 
  "link": "link", 
  "username": "username", 
  "gender": "male", 
  "timezone": 2, 
  "locale": "en_US", 
  "verified": true, 
  "updated_time": "2012-07-16T13:00:04+0000"
}
```

Pretty similar information like in the first case.

But again - I cannot get the email address. I've tried also

```
print_r($facebook->api('/my_username_or_id?fields=email'));
```

and the same also on FB developer site, but again without success...

Is there any way to get email address from ID/username?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an email address for a user, you need to have a user access token or have them authenticated in an app with the `email` permission granted.

This gives you the email for that user only. You can't get a user's friend's email address this way.

This prevents spammers from harvesting emails from Facebook.

Comment: I have access token and my access token has user_friends,public_profile how to i get user email id? important thing i get user id and name of the user only one i need that is user email how to i get email from using userId? @ cpiko

Comment: how to add scope to access token and how to get email? if any example or suggestion pls share

Answer (score 3):

By using facebook api you can only fetch your own e-mail id in your result sets. I think because of security reasons facebook doesn't provide another users e-mail ids.

Comment: 5 years later this appears to still be the case.