# how to get a user's @facebook email address

Tags: facebook, email

I am developing a Facebook app and have implemented the login dialog. I'd like to get the user's @facebook email address (example johnsmith@facebook.com).  Is there a method of getting this info at all? Thanks!

Comment: Find the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/3611781/842850 you can get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Without doing a lot of research (I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader) I believe the users Facebook's email address is simply the user's username put in front of @facebook.com. e.g. "username"@facebook.com.

Username is accessible in in the Graph.

Knowing this you could take a good guess at what the user's email address.

That said, this is obviously not an officially sanctioned method and even if it does work it might fall foul of the Facebook TOS, so buyer beware!

Answer (score 1):

Legacy Rest API *(in the deprecating process, so it's not recommended)* has users.getInfo

Graph API has the User object where you can fetch fields/information of the user *(through fields query like: graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email or you can try it in the [Grap API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/))*

The data that will show depends on the users account privacy or permissions granted by the app (you also need access tokens). if you don't have the permission to that information, the query will return empty/no data for the requested field.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

i'm also new in developing facebook apps. maybe em 50% wrong :D

Comment: Using the Graph API, I can get the email address (of course), but it does not specifically allow me to get the @facebook email address.