# Where can I get the user email?

Tags: facebook, json, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Graph API, how to get users email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611682/facebook-graph-api-how-to-get-users-email)

Well, in my application, I ask the user to grant permission for me to get his email ... let's say that he does ...

According to the code of API reference, the `FB.getLoginStatus` function returns a Json Object with the following contents:

`{
    status: 'connected',
    authResponse: {
        accessToken: '...',
        expiresIn:'...',
        signedRequest:'...',
        userID:'...'
    }
}`

So, assuming the user has accepted the terms, and granted permission for email to my app, where is the email value? It's in a new child in the `FB.getLoginStatus` response? Something like:

`{
    status: 'connected',
    authResponse: {
        accessToken: '...',
        expiresIn:'...',
        signedRequest:'...',
        userID:'...'
        userEmail:'....'
    }
}`

In PHP, I use something like that:

`json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/SOMEIDHERE'))->name;` (a resquest to graph.facebook.com, for example)

But it's not what i'm looking for.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the User data, you have to make an API call to:
`http://graph.facebook.com/user_id` and inside the response you will get the user email (if already approved the email permission).

Comment: It seems little bit confused to me. I need only the user Id? So any app that has the user id can access the information from the User? I need not inform a token, or the key of my application?

Comment: By default you can get only the public user data if you have an id. After a user approves the required permissions it's possible to access some private user data. You can test this here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer