# facebook login - email not working anymore

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-login

I'm using the facebook sdk to let users login to my website. This code was working until today, in fact it returns (from now) an error referred to the last row.

```
//FACEBOOK SDK CODE
//--------------------------------------------------------------

require 'facebookSDK/src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));


// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl();
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
  header('location: '.$loginUrl);
  exit;
}

// This call will always work since we are fetching public data.
$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');


//----------------------------------------------------------------

$facebook_id=$user_profile['id'];
$facebook_name=$user_profile['name'];
$facebook_email=$user_profile['email'];
```

Undefined index 'email'.
I have no idea about what to do! it was working since now...
I need to get the user's email, the 'name' and the 'id' parameters are ok, but not 'email'.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try **var_dump($user_profile)** before the 3 last lines, what do you get?

Comment: I get only the following parameters with no email: ["name"]["first_name"]["last_name"]["link"]["quotes"]["sports"]["id"]["name"]["id"]["name"]["id"]["name"]["id"]["name"]["favorite_teams"]["id"]["name"]["gender"]["timezone"]["locale"]["languages"]["id"]["name"]["id"]["name"]["verified"]["updated_time"]["username"]. Id and name are used fors sports, films, for this reason there are many times

Comment: It's not possible no get the email of the user right away. More information about it in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611682/facebook-graph-api-how-to-get-users-email (Possible Duplicate)

Comment: I changed "$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();" into "$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email,read_stream'));" but it still doesn't work

Comment: Now it works just by doing nothing...I don't know!!!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has updated its api

Change this line to
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=email');