# Can/How we get email ids of a Facebook user in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a website where I am pulling user information from Facebook. 
If user logs in to my website using Facebook authentication. I can pull his friend list from Facebook with user-id of each friend.
Is it possible to retrieve email id of them as I have user id?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot retrieve the email addresses of the users' friends. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611682/facebook-graph-api-how-to-get-users-email):

> The only way to get the users e-mail address is to request extended permissions on the email field. The user must allow you to see this and you cannot get the e-mail addresses of the user's friends.