# Login using facebook get username, email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using login using facebook in my website,

Here is the button

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

I am using the exact example given [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web)

But after the check login status, i am getting the response with only the userid of facebook and token, but i want to get the username too.. How can i get that ?

Help pls

Here is the script

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'xxxx',
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
            // the session
            xfbml: true, // parse social plugins on this page
            version: 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.email);

            //here status is connected
            //statusChangeCallback(response);
        });

    };
```

In the `resopnse`, i am getting the entire json,

In the `response.status` i am getting as connected

But while i try `response.email` i am getting undefined

How can i get the email or username ?

Comment: it means.. you have not configured the facebook login app properly at fb.. check for the app status on fb.. whether it is active or still inactive..

Comment: in the facebook developer page ?

Comment: yes.. on the fb developers page.. in the app settings..

Comment: In the app setting, i can see only the app id, website, namespace, email.. like that only..

Comment: Could you pls tell, where i should mention the parameters that i want to get from user..

Comment: Username is not available through the API. Email you can only get if you ask for the field

Comment: ok, can u say where or how i can get the email..

Comment: If you post it as a answer, it will be helpful for me sir

Comment: http://www.krizna.com/demo/login-with-facebook-using-php/ check this tutorial..

Comment: have you tried this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611682/facebook-graph-api-how-to-get-users-email)?? This may help you with what you want.

Comment: seems everything ok with your code.. only thing is. you need to make your app active on fb developers page..

Comment: It was in active stage... it shows green dot in near the app name..

Comment: The app was active and the approved stage are email, public_profile, and user friends ..

Comment: i suggest you read this: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/ - don´t use php for login, especially if you are a beginner. the javascript sdk is MUCH easier to handle.

Comment: getLoginStatus is only for checking the user login status, you don´t make an api call anywhere in your code, so of course you don´t get the email.

Comment: @luschn May i know how can i get the username or email from the api call ?

Comment: you need to start using google. this has been discussed a hundred times. username is not available anymore, not sure what for you would need it anyway. and there are a lot of threads about how to get the email too. read the article i commented and try to understand what´s happening with the login first. and THEN think about getting additional data.

Comment: I have two facebook apps. One that I created today that has the exact same problem described above (no email returned) and another than I created more than a year ago but never used. Both are active. When I run code against the new one it does not return email. When I run the exact same code against the older on, I get email. I wonder if FB limits what data they return for brand new apps.

Comment: It happens few time, but for me mostly it returns all data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED to show what actually fixed it for me:

So it does appear to depend on what version of the API your config is set to allow. BUT, I was able to get the email address on a v2.5 api by using the following:

If you are using the Hello World code, then replace this section:

```
FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                        console.log('Success ');
                        console.log(response);
                    });
```

With this:

```
FB.api('/me', { fields: 'email' }, function (response) {
                        console.log('Success ');
                        console.log(response);
                    });
```

The difference is adding the { fields: 'email' } object to the call. This appears to have been a new addition in either v2.4 or v2.5 of the API which is why older code you see on SO appears to work for the poster but not for you. Hope this helps.

---

I'm not sure this qualifies as a solution, but I was able to reproduce this issue (no email returned after a valid request).

I have two apps, each created under a different FB account. The first one was created more than a year ago and the second one was created today. I have code that runs perfectly against the older app (returns email) and fails against the newer app (no email).

At first I thought maybe FB just holds back on certain data for brand new apps but I thought it was odd that it wouldnt be documented anywhere.

So I decided to compare each app configuration side by side. I found that the older one had API VERSION (at the top of the dashboard) set to 2.0 and the newer was 2.5. The Hello World code on the API SDK page requests version 2.2 like so:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: [my app id here],
                cookie: true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                // the session
                xfbml: true,  // parse social plugins on this page
                version: 'v2.2' 
            })
        };
```

According to the documentation, the fact that the newer app has API set to 2.5 in the config means that any requests for an older API (eg 2.2) will be automatically upgraded to 2.5. When I set the javascript above to request 2.5 (eg version: 'v2.5'), I was able to get the older app to fail too. So I suspect the issue is with the newer v2.5 api.

I have not been able to find out how to set my new app to accept older api calls but will update here if I do.