# In Facebook Graph API, what are the API calls to get a user's email address

Tags: facebook-graph-api, get

Here I'm simply sending a GET request through a rest client.It returns only user id and name .Additionally, how do I retrieve user's email using only a GET request?

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token= [User's access token]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=name,email&access_token=[User's access token]
```

It´s called "Declarative Fields" and came with v2.4 of the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

API Explorer test: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dname%2Cemail

Of course you need to use a User Token that includes the `email` permission/scope. Debug your Token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: still returns only the user id and name

Comment: then you either don´t have an approved email or you did not try with a user token that includes the email permission.

Comment: i added a link to the token debugger in my answer, see if the email permission is visible

Comment: Did you try sending this as a GET request through any rest client such as postman?

Comment: you can just test api calls in the official api explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dname%2Cemail&version=v2.6

Comment: yes you can, of course, I do get the email value when using official graph explorer. But I want to test it with a rest client. Since my application a invokes a GET request.

Comment: did you test it by selecting YOUR app in the api explorer? you can even put that api call into the browser for testing, you don´t need any platform.

Comment: did you test your user token in the token debugger too?

Comment: Thanks, it worked , I had to provide  permission scope as email and select the app

Answer (score 3):

I know this is sort of an old question, but just so anyone else misses it: even if you give permission when generating the token, if the user doesn't have an email registered to his/her facebook account or hasn't confirmed the email yet, facebook won't return it when you query.

You can see this on the Graph API Explorer:
[image]

Hope this helps :)