# Angular2 ng2-facebook-sdk component - requesting email permissions

Tags: angular, facebook-graph-api

I have an Angular2 app which is using a third party component for Facebook authentication. The component is quite good but I am having problems adding a permission request to the authentication url.

Has anyone used the component named [ng2-facebook-sdk](https://github.com/zyramedia/ng2-facebook-sdk)? 
If so does anyone know how I would go about adding a parameter to the authentication url as described in this question...

[Facebook Graph API, how to get users email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611682/facebook-graph-api-how-to-get-users-email)

Currently my code looks like this...

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    let fbParams: FacebookInitParams = {
        appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.6'
    };
    this.fb.init(fbParams);

    this.fb.login().then(...
}
```

As per the above post I want to...

> "You can do this if you are using Facebook connect by passing
>   scope=email in the get string of your call to the Auth Dialog."

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself, you can pass a param into the login call...

```
let options: FacebookLoginOptions = {
        scope: 'email'
    }

    this.fb.login(options).then(
```